# Adding image folder to public domain a2 hosting

Tags: html, css, image, hosting

Hi I am really new to coding so please explain stuff really simply :) My friend has created a website and I added some html/css but the images on css come from local image folders and cannot display on the public domain. How can I add a new image folder to the domain folders that has my images. We are using a2hosting and I am using SFTP/FTP on sublime text as the editor? 
At the moment all I am able to do in terms of adding stuff is adding files and then naming them.

Comment: 1) Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
2) it is impossible to answer to your question. You provided few info and it is hard to understand what is your actual problem.

Comment: I am not very sure what you mean but: You should upload the images into the same folder as the html files that call these images. Name them accordingly to what <img src=""> says.